# Solutions to $(x-x_0)\cos(x_0)+\sin(x_0)-\sin(x)=0$

Tags: trigonometry, tangent-line

A tangent line to the sine function at the point $\{x_0, \sin(x_0)\}$, will intersect the sine at the points where
$$(x-x_0)\cos(x_0)+\sin(x_0)-\sin(x)=0$$
The solutions to that equation looks like this:

[image: Solutions to (x-x_0)*cos(x_0)+sin(x_0)-sin(x)=0]

There's the obvious $x_0=x$ solution, and all the other solutions are the same function, only shifted along the $x_0=x$ line. I'm interested in these solutions, but since they're all the same function but shifted, I'm focusing on the middle one.

If I plot just the middle one:

[image: Plot of the desired function]

I've tried finding it analytically, to no avail, and functions I thought looked similar (for example $\mathrm{Si}(x)$) are not solutions to the equation.

Can anyone help me to be able to plot this function without just doing Newton steps to solve it?

I'm interested in the solution for all values of $x_0$ in the range $\left[-\frac{1}{2}\pi; \frac{1}{2}\pi\right]$ and all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (the same as my second plot)

Comment: Please calarify whether you want all valid values of $a$ or whether you want to draw the equation (you need a specific $a$ value for this).

Comment: @NoChance I updated my question ($a$ is now $x_0$), and in order to plot the function, I need many values for $x_0$ (it is on the second axis)

Answer (score 0):

Let $$P(x_0,\sin(x_0))$$ then the equation of the tangent line is given by $$y=\cos(x_0)(x-x_0)+\sin(x_0)$$ so we get
$$\sin(x)=\cos(x_0)(x-x_0)+\sin(x_0)$$ Substituting $x=a$ we get
$$\sin(a)=\cos(x_0)(a-x_0)+\sin(x_0)$$ there is a difference to your equation, you have
$$(a-x)\cos(a)+\sin(x)-\sin(a)=0$$?

Comment: I had swapped $x$ and $a$ in my definition of the equation, sorry about that. I have updated my question (and adopted your $x_0$ as the name as I think it makes it clearer)

Answer (score 0):

It was too long for a comment, so I post it as an answer.:
 Let try this question as a simple case: from point (0,0) which is between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ a line tangent to the curve $y=sin x$ is drawn. find the coordinates of point the line touches the curve. We can estimate the coordinates as follows: draw a line from (0, 0) to minimum point (3\pi/2, -1). the gradient of line is:

$tan (\alpha)=\frac{-1}{3\pi/2} ≈-0.2123$ and $\alpha ≈-12^o$.

the point of tangent is near $(x=3\pi/2, y=-1)$. Let $x_0=180+[(90-12)=78^o]$.

$cos (180+78)=-cos 78=-0.2079$ is the gradient of tangent line due to the formula which is near the value of [$tan (-12^o)$]. So the coordinates of point of touch  a is almost $(x_a=180 +78=258 ≈44\pi/30, y_a=-0.978)$.If the point of intersection is $(x_0, y_0)$ and point of touch is $(x_a, y_a)$ we can write:

$m=\frac{y_a-y_0}{x_a-x_0}=cos(x_a)$

This is a sort of Diophantine equation.I took minimum point $(3\pi/2, -1)$ for rough estimation of tangent coordinates.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're doing. At (0,0) $x_0=0$, and the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$ so the slope at that point is $\cos(0)=1$. And for exactly $x_0=0$, it only touches the curve once, and that's at the tangent point $x=0$.

Comment: @Atnas, sorry about it I edited my answer.

Comment: I'm still confused because the only solution for $x_0=0$ is $x=0$ as I wrote before. Here's an illustration: https://i.imgur.com/t4hHc5e.png
You can see that the red line only intersects the blue at $x=0$

Comment: @Atnas, I can not open your illustrations. If you want to understand what I mean, plot $y=sin (x)$, draw a line from origin tangent to curve near point $(3\pi/2, -1)$.Another example: draw a line tangent to curve at point $(5\pi/4, -\sqrt 2/2)$, it crosses the curve at point $(x_0, y_0)$. to find $x_0$ and $y_0$ you have to solve equation:$sin(x) +(\sqrt 2/2)x +(\sqrt 2/2)[1-5\pi/4]=0$. I think numerical method works.